# Drag, Drop, Sort, Clone and Change Class Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, drag-and-drop, droppable

> ### Here's what I'm trying to accomplish
>
> **(Version 2.0 New Code Updates)**
>
> I'm trying to create a module that has 2 columns. A left and a right. I want the buttons in the left column when dropped into the right to change classes. When the buttons on the left are dropped on the right I want them to call an animated class that is per-defined that transitions in a larger image. These boxes will then be drag and droppable in the right column.
>
> Again I need this module to drag, drop, clone, sort and change classes. I have everything figured out except for the changing of classes. I've been working on this for some time now so any insight is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

---

### Here's a picture and my code

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to accomplish - [Twitter Pic](https://twitter.com/lukeslytalker/status/504717554435514368).

Here's [my new fiddle for this project](http://jsfiddle.net/lukeslytalker/h4mk29wg/7/).

---

### Suggested code that isn't working

Here's my latest effort to alter the javascript as advised on this post. This script still isn't working. I understand what I'm trying to do, but something is missing. Little help anyone?

```
$('ui-sortable-handle').droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
       if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('music')){
       $(this).addClass("droppedlimusic");
    }
        else if($(this).attr('id').indexOf('nav')){
       $(this).addClass("droppedlinav");
    }
},
over: function(event, ui) {},
out: function(event, ui) {}
});
```

### The following code is version 3 of my work which still isn't working...sigh..

```
$("#left-pane li").draggable({
    containment: '#gbox',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false,
    connectToSortable: '#right-pane',
    appendTo: '#right-pane',
    start: function () {},
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
}).mousedown(function () {});

$("#right-pane").sortable({
    sort: function () {},
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    receive: function () {},
    update: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("#right-pane li").live('dblclick', function () {
    $(this).remove();
})

$("#right-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#left-pane li",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable).find('.single-item').length == 0) {
            $(ui.draggable).append("<div class='single-item'><input type='text' class='item-title' /><br /><textarea class='item-text'></textarea></div>");
        }
    }
});

$("#left-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#right-pane li",
    drop: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("ul, li").disableSelection();
```

### Original Module HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-column">
        <ul id="left-pane">
            <li class="music"><a href=""><img src="http://www.natebal.com/images/seo.jpg" width="55px" /></a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href=""><img src="http://www.natebal.com/images/social-networks.jpg" width="55px" /></a></li>
            <li class="phone"><a href=""><img src="http://www.natebal.com/images/sweet-web-development.jpg" width="55px" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        <ul id="right-pane"></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us the html too

Comment: if ($( "#music" ).hasClass( "droppedlimusic" )) ?

Comment: @NateBalcom I suggest editing your question with this info.

Comment: This is what I'm looking to do. 

`if($('li').hasId('#music').addClass('droppedlimusic').removeClass("a:link")){ }` 

Basically if list item has the id #music add class droppedlimusic and remove a:link. This happens on drop so I guess I have to make this a droppable event as well.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
if($('#music').attr('class').indexOf("droppedlimusic")){
    //dialog show
}
```

use:

```
if( $("#music").hasClass('droppedlimusic') )
```

because if your element has another class (like, I don't know, 'playing' or 'yellow' or 'whatyouwant') `$('#music').attr('class')` is equal to `droppedlimusic playing`, which is different from `droppedlimusic`

```
$( "yourdroppable item" ).droppable({
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        if($(this).hasClass('yourclass')){
           $(this)
           .attr('id', "your id")
           .removeClass("yourclass");
        }
    },
    over: function( event, ui ) {},
    out: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Hope this will do the trick
I don't know if you want to edit the class of the div that you drop the element on $(this) or the element that you're dropping ui.draggable

Comment: Currently buttons from the left column drop onto the right with the applied animation I assigned. It isn't however pulling the correct class "droppedlimusic".

Comment: @NateBalcom change hasId to .attr('id').indexOf('yourid').

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are searching for..

```
if($('#music').hasClass('droppedlimusic')){
   //your code
}
```